# Create Table in entity framework mvc 4 programmatically

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

i build an asp web application before using VS10 and use ado.net to connect database , 
my project need to build table programmatically , in project admin can build new templates ( tables ) for their Instances
in ado.net by create table query we can do that so easy

i want to rebuild my application with mvc 4 and entity framework
and i cant find way to do that

is there any way to Create Model or Table programmatically  in mvc 4 ?
or you have any way to do my work with entity framework ?

Comment: Entity Framework is an ORM. It's not intended for database management type of applications.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i found it , for create dynamic tables in database best way is use ado.net codes directly in mvc4 
use old way to do that , then our project use two way for use database , entity framework for main tables ( models) and ado.net for dynamic tables